# Callback after sharing intent completes

Tags: android, android-intent, callback, share

I'm using the following code to share stuff on my android app:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "blah blah blah");
this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose a sharing option:"));
```

I need to know if the user did share with success or if it failed. Is there anyway to get a callback when the sharing action is complete?

Comment: If I read your question correctly and you're using 3rd-party apps to 'share' (e.g., facebook, twitter etc) then it's unlikely your app will be able to receive any success/failure response using `ACTION_SEND`. In particular `startActivity(...)` has no facility for responses and you'd need to use `startActivityForResult(...)` for example. Even then, it would rely on the various 3rd-party apps implementing the functionality to return a result. The only way you could do this is using development libraries and APIs if they exist for the 3rd-party apps.

Comment: I need to know if the user was able to share successfully to facebook and twitter. I noticed that using startActivityForResult(…) does not give me whether or not the user shared with success. Do you think their api's would support this?

Comment: As I said, it is unlikely that most 3rd-party apps will return a sensible result when started with `startActivityForResult`. The reason for this is those apps don't 'know' what sort of result you want or whether your app can understand anything they may return. As for their apis supporting it, I don't know as I've never programmed for fb or twitter - I would guess they do as various apps I use (YouTube as a simple example) can tell me if I successfully shared or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use startActivityForResult, that ways will be able to check the response. Please check:
[startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

If you need to have more control on the process, you shouldn't use the Sharing Intent approach. Instead you can use Twitter4j library for twitter and the Facebook SDK for Android for Facebook sharing.

Comment: It will not work. It depends weather the app you opened sends result back or not.If it doesn't then you always get result code other than RESULT_OK

Comment: Indeed it does not work. But at least I get a callback, but I need more than that.

Comment: @KetanAhir is right, but I think it's the only option you have in that case. If you want to have more control on the process, then you can't use the Sharing Intent approach.

Comment: Always comes back with cancel result